# Using pandas to convert excel sheet with formulas to csv

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, formula

I am new to pandas and using it to convert and excel sheet with formulas to csv.
As expected, I want to just copy the values. However, in my csv I am getting the header but all other cells have "0" reported.

```
 import pandas as pd
   data_xls = pd.read_excel('my_result.xlsx', 'Dashboard', index_col=None)
   data_xls.to_csv('myabc_result.csv', encoding='utf-8',index=False)
```

The formula in original excel sheet looks like this(surprisingly every cell has similar formula):

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("Results!"&MATCH(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","")&"$1"),Results!$A:$A,0)&":"&MATCH(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","")&"$1"),Results!$A:$A,0)),1,INDIRECT("$A"&ROW())+1)
```

Thanks,

Comment: If I remember correctly, pandas read formulas in excel as values. So in your case, the csv will be automatically saved in values.

Comment: But, I am getting every cell value as 0. Only the header is printed correctly in csv.

Comment: What is a sample of the data, and what does `data_xls.head()` show, and how is that different from what you expect?

Comment: in your pandas df are you getting all the values ?